# Multiple instances of the CompiledScript

Tags: java, scala, scriptengine

I am loading a Scala script through the ScriptEngine and use CompiledScript to eval the script.

I am using a Java interface to map the Scala script to java side as below.

Java Interface:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
     void method1();
}
```

Scala Script:

```
class ScalaImp extends SomeInterface {
   override def method1() : Unit = {
    //Implementation
   }

}
```

The code that loads the object of type `SomeInterface` is as following.

```
String extension = path.getFileName().toString();
extension = extension.substring(extension.lastIndexOf(".") > 0 ? extension.lastIndexOf(".") + 1 : 0);
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension(extension);
File file = path.toFile();

if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
    SomeInterface mappingInterface = null;
    SomeInterface mappingInterface2 = null;
    try(FileReader fr = new FileReader(file)) {

        Compilable compilable = (Compilable)engine;
        CompiledScript compiledScript = compilable.compile(fr);

        mappingInterface = (SomeInterface)compiledScript.eval();
        mappingInterface2 = (SomeInterface)compiledScript.eval(); //This fails. Any alternative for this?

    }
    catch (FileSystemException e) {
        logger.error("Cannot load file");
    }

    return mappingInterface;
}
```

I want to create multiple instances of the script. But the above code gives following error: `Failed to load '$line6.$eval': $line6.$eval` at the second `eval()` call. I know I can use multiple CompiledScript instances and evaluate separately. But the compilation takes too long and exceeds the program's performance expectation.

Is there anyway that I can create multiple instances of the same script with one CompiledScript instance?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. It works by using the REPL, which always compiles to evaluate code in 2.12 and earlier.

Probably you're attempting:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_144).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val s = scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Scripted()
s: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Scripted = scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Scripted@432f4626

scala> s.eval("class C")
res0: Object = null

scala> val c = s.compile("new C")
c: javax.script.CompiledScript = scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Scripted$WrappedRequest@13346a64

scala> c.eval()
res1: Object = C@2d093067

scala> c.eval()
res2: Object = C@2693e39c
```

You can observe the compilation work:

```
scala> s.intp.settings.Xprint.value_=(List("typer"))
```

On the second eval, it reuses the class that wraps the user code, but it compiles a new wrapper that forwards definitions. It looks like there is a bug where it attempts to forward both value definitions and types; in this case, the class definition doesn't work.

Probably you don't intend to define two different classes, but return two instances of the same class, as shown?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I want to create two instances of the same class. So in that case is there a work around for it? Would it be something related to the following bug? https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8669?orig=1

Comment: My example creates two instance of C, but the definition of C can't be in the compiled script line.

Comment: I get a similar error. Failed to load '$line6.$eval':  Need a small suggestion. Would using the cloneable interface to clone the created object would have any unseen issues?